The proposal is always as pending state?
I try this smart contract with hardhat test mode but the state is always on pending
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/Governor.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorSettings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorCountingSimple.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotes.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotesQuorumFraction.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorTimelockControl.sol";

contract TestTokenGovernor is
    Governor,
    GovernorSettings,
    GovernorCountingSimple,
    GovernorVotes,
    GovernorVotesQuorumFraction,
    GovernorTimelockControl
{
    uint256[] private allProposals;
    mapping(uint256 => string) public proposalDescriptions;

    constructor(
        IVotes _token,
        TimelockController _timelock
    )
        Governor("TestTokenGovernor")
        GovernorSettings(5, 25, 0)
        GovernorVotes(_token)
        GovernorVotesQuorumFraction(4)
        GovernorTimelockControl(_timelock)
    {}

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function votingDelay()
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingDelay();
    }

    function votingPeriod()
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingPeriod();
    }

    function quorum(
        uint256 blockNumber
    )
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorVotesQuorumFraction)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.quorum(blockNumber);
    }

    function state(
        uint256 proposalId
    )
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (ProposalState)
    {
        return super.state(proposalId);
    }

    function proposalNeedsQueuing(
        uint256 proposalId
    ) public view override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl) returns (bool) {
        return super.proposalNeedsQueuing(proposalId);
    }

    function proposalThreshold()
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.proposalThreshold();
    }

    function _queueOperations(
        uint256 proposalId,
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        bytes32 descriptionHash
    ) internal override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl) returns (uint48) {
        return
            super._queueOperations(
                proposalId,
                targets,
                values,
                calldatas,
                descriptionHash
            );
    }

    function _executeOperations(
        uint256 proposalId,
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        bytes32 descriptionHash
    ) internal override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl) {
        super._executeOperations(
            proposalId,
            targets,
            values,
            calldatas,
            descriptionHash
        );
    }

    function _cancel(
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        bytes32 descriptionHash
    ) internal override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl) returns (uint256) {
        return super._cancel(targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _executor()
        internal
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (address)
    {
        return super._executor();
    }

    // Function to propose a new proposal
    function propose(
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        string memory description
    ) public override returns (uint256) {
        uint256 proposalId = super.propose(
            targets,
            values,
            calldatas,
            description
        );
        allProposals.push(proposalId); // Track the new proposal
        proposalDescriptions[proposalId] = description; // Store the proposal description
        return proposalId;
    }

    // Function to list all proposals
    function listAllProposals() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return allProposals;
    }

    // Function to get details of a specific proposal
    function getProposalDetails(
        uint256 proposalId
    )
        public
        view
        returns (
            string memory proposalDescription,
            ProposalState proposalState,
            uint256 proposalQuorum
        )
    {
        proposalDescription = proposalDescriptions[proposalId];
        proposalState = state(proposalId);
        proposalQuorum = quorum(proposalSnapshot(proposalId));
    }

    // Mapping to store proposal descriptions
    mapping(uint256 => string) public proposalsDescription;

    function _storeProposalDescription(
        uint256 proposalId,
        string memory description
    ) internal {
        proposalsDescription[proposalId] = description;
    }
}

The test code
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, upgrades } = require("hardhat");
const { time } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");
require("dotenv").config();

const { USDTADDR, USDCADDR, TOKENADDR, TIMELOCKADDR, GOVERNORADDR, CROWDSALE } = process.env;

describe("TestToken and TestTokenGovernor Integration", function () {
  let TestToken, TestTokenGovernor, TimelockController;
  let testToken, governor, timelock;
  let deployer, proposer, executor, feeWallet;
  const initialSupply = ethers.parseUnits("10000", 18);

  before(async function () {
    // Get the signers
    [deployer, proposer, executor, feeWallet, voter1, voter2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    // Get contract factories
    TestToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestToken");
    TimelockController = await ethers.getContractFactory("TimelockController");
    TestTokenGovernor = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestTokenGovernor");
  });

  describe("Proxy Deployment", function () {
    it("Should deploy the TestToken contract via proxy", async function () {
      testToken = await upgrades.deployProxy(TestToken, [feeWallet.address, 3, deployer.address], {
        initializer: 'initialize',
        kind: "uups"
      });
      await testToken.waitForDeployment();
      expect(testToken.target).to.be.properAddress;
      console.log("TestToken deployed to (proxy):", testToken.target);
    });

    it("Should deploy the TimelockController contract", async function () {
      timelock = await TimelockController.deploy(2 * 60, [proposer.address], [executor.address], deployer.address);
      await timelock.waitForDeployment();
      expect(timelock.target).to.be.properAddress;
      console.log("TimelockController deployed to:", timelock.target);
    });

    it("Should deploy the TestTokenGovernor contract", async function () {
      governor = await TestTokenGovernor.deploy(testToken.target, timelock.target);
      await governor.waitForDeployment();
      expect(governor.target).to.be.properAddress;
      console.log("TestTokenGovernor deployed to:", governor.target);


    });

    it("Should have correct initial settings for TestTokenGovernor", async function () {
      expect(await governor.votingDelay()).to.equal(60); // 1 minute
      expect(await governor.votingPeriod()).to.equal(5 * 60); // 5 minutes
      expect(await governor.quorum(0)).to.equal(0); // 4% quorum
    });

    it("Should have correct initial settings for TestToken", async function () {
      expect(await testToken.name()).to.equal("TestToken");
      expect(await testToken.symbol()).to.equal("TSSZ");
      expect(await testToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ethers.parseEther("20000000")); // 10 million initial supply

      console.log(await testToken.getAddress());
      console.log(deployer.address);
    });

    it("should allow proposing, voting, and executing a proposal", async function () {
      // Create a proposal to mint new tokens
      const amountToMint = ethers.parseUnits("1000", 18);
      const targets = [testToken.target];
      const values = [0];
      const calldatas = [
        testToken.interface.encodeFunctionData("mint", [deployer.address, amountToMint]),
      ];
      const description = "Proposal #1: Mint 1000 new tokens";


      // Delegate votes
      await testToken.connect(deployer).delegate(voter1.address);
      await testToken.approve(voter1.address, initialSupply / 2n);
      await testToken.transfer(voter1.address, initialSupply / 2n);
      await testToken.approve(voter2.address, initialSupply / 2n);
      await testToken.transfer(voter2.address, initialSupply / 2n);

      await testToken.connect(voter1).delegate(voter1.address);
      await testToken.connect(voter2).delegate(voter2.address);

      // Propose the proposal
      const tx = await governor.connect(proposer).propose(targets, values, calldatas, description);
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
      const proposalId = receipt.logs[0].args.proposalId;

      console.log("Proposal ID: ", proposalId);

      let currentTime = await time.latest();
      console.log("Current Blockchain Time (Unix Timestamp):", currentTime.toString());

      // Advance time to start voting
      const stateBefore_time = await governor.state(proposalId);
      console.log(stateBefore_time);

      await time.increase(12000000); // increase time by 1 minute (votingDelay)
      // Get the snapshot block and advance time to make the proposal "Active"

      currentTime = await time.latest();
      console.log("Current Blockchain Time (Unix Timestamp):", currentTime.toString());

      const allProposals = await governor.listAllProposals();
      console.log(allProposals);

      // Queue the proposal (if passed)
      const stateBefore = await governor.state(proposalId);
      console.log(stateBefore);

      await time.increase(600); // increase time by 1 minute (votingDelay)
      const stateBefore_2 = await governor.state(proposalId);
      console.log(stateBefore_2);
      // Cast votes
      await governor.connect(voter1).castVote(proposalId, 1); // 1 = For
      await governor.connect(voter2).castVote(proposalId, 0); // 0 = Against

      // Advance time to end voting
      await time.increase(5 * 60); // increase time by 5 minutes (votingPeriod)

      // Queue the proposal (if passed)
      const state = await governor.state(proposalId);
      console.log(state);

      /*
      if (state === 4) { // 4 = Succeeded
        await governor.queue(targets, values, calldatas, ethers.id(description));

        // Advance time to pass the timelock delay
        await time.increase(minDelay);

        // Execute the proposal
        await governor.execute(targets, values, calldatas, ethers.id(description));

        // Verify that the tokens were minted
        const balance = await testToken.balanceOf(deployer.address);
        expect(balance).to.equal(initialSupply + amountToMint);
      } else {
        expect(state).to.equal(3); // 3 = Defeated
      }
      */

    });
  });
});

